# array in a separate class other than main method/class

Tags: java, arrays, subclass

I keep getting this error, its about needing braces after the array decleration.
[image]

I do not know what to do about this. I want to make an array that is not in my main method. I want the array to be supertype populated with subclass.
Here is my code

```
public class ArrayTest {

Employee [] employees = new Manager[2];
employees[0]= new Manager("Thomas", "Cummings");

}


public class Manager extends Employee{
private int employees;

public Manager() {
    super();
    employees = 0;
}

public Manager(int employees) {
    super();
    this.employees = employees;
}

public Manager(String f_name, String l_name) {
    super(f_name, l_name);
}

public Manager(String f_name, String l_name, int employees) {
    super(f_name, l_name);
    this.employees = employees;
}

public int getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(int employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}

public void setManager(String f_name, String l_name){
    this.setF_name(f_name);
    this.setL_name(l_name);
}

public void setManager(String f_name, String l_name, int employees){
    this.setF_name(f_name);
    this.setL_name(l_name);
    this.employees = employees;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "\nName " + getF_name() + " " + getL_name() +
            "\nEmployee ID " + getEmp_id() + 
            "\nNum of employees " + getEmployees();
}
}


public class Employee {

private String f_name, l_name;
private static long emp_id = 001;

public Employee(){
    f_name = "";
    l_name = "";
    emp_id ++;
}
public Employee(String f_name, String l_name) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
    this.l_name = l_name;
    emp_id ++;
}
public String getF_name() {
    return f_name;
}
public void setF_name(String f_name) {
    this.f_name = f_name;
}
public String getL_name() {
    return l_name;
}
public void setL_name(String l_name) {
    this.l_name = l_name;
}
public long getEmp_id() {
    return emp_id;
}
public void setEmp_id(long emp_id) {
    Employee.emp_id = emp_id;
}

public String toString(){
    return "\nName " + getF_name() + " " + getL_name() +
            "\nEmployee ID " + getEmp_id();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of error is the following statement:

```
employees[0]= new Manager("Thomas", "Cummings");
```

as you cannot put executable statements outside of code blocks(methods, blocks, constructors) in a java class.

One way to resolve this problem is by moving the initialization statement in a constructor:

```
public class ArrayTest {

Employee [] employees = new Manager[2];

public ArrayTest() {
    employees[0]= new Manager("Thomas", "Cummings");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
employees[0]= new Manager("Thomas", "Cummings");
```

this is an statement which needs to be placed in proper executable block (method, constructor, initialization block)